# MySQL Update Other Rows to Keep Track of Current / Latest

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

i am working an intranet project so i can't copy/paste code so hopefully my description and maybe some small snippets will help.

i know MySQL trigger can't do this but was hoping of a JPA PrePersist (or similar) way that is clean (minimal code.)

we have queries that are kind of ugly because we seem to need to find the "latest" all the time.  So if we have a PersonCar entity based on a join table then we seem to be needing to find the most recent row with person_id = x and car_id = y.  so we were thinking of adding an is_current flag to our entities (and database tables.)  our choices were...

1. keep having queries where something like "where person_car_id = (select max(pc) from PersonCar where person_id = x and car_id = y)"
2. user a view to get the latest person/car row
3. add is_current that has the latest PersonCar row set to true and false for all other rows of *that* PersonCar relationship.

we wanted to try #3.  but then in MySQL you can't do a pre-trigger to update all other rows with the same person_id and car_id to have is_current = false before inserting a new row and assigning is_current true.

so, i was looking into a JPA way to do what we want.

a PrePersist that will do an update: update person_car set is_current = false where person_id = same_person_id_as_current_insert and car_id = same_car_id as current_insert;

note that we do use a combination of direct Spring Data repository calls from the UI along with controller calls as well.

**what is the best way to achieve this?**

i was hoping there would be a strictly annotation way to do this or adding a JDBC like update query in a method of the entity and annotate it with @PrePersist or something simple.  but also, if people have good reason not to do it this way i'm all up for listening too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having as isCurrent flag in your entities why not have a timestamp that is updated in a PrePersist / PreUpdate method. Then on the server side you can do some simple DateTime comparison to find out which objects are the most current.

Comment: that's basically what we do now and it makes every query have to have extra in it to determine which is the max.  we actually used the max(primary_key) even though we also have a create_date in each object already.  just in some of our complex joins it seems nicer to just add to the where clause "and is_current = true"